# Using regex to modify multiple files in Python

Tags: regex, python-2.7, overwrite

I need to be able to open a txt file, read it as a string, use regex to replace items in the string (getting rid of non-alpha and numeric characters), and then write to the file so the original file is "cleaned."

This seems simple, but I am a beginner and it is not. I can open files, do all of the stuff in the middle, and save the changes to a single file (use glob and re.sub), but cannot figure out how to just make changes to the original file and save it.

All help appreciated! First time poster Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to know how to manipulate the content, I'll just give you a framework for working with your file.

```
try:
    # 'r+' opens the file for both reading and writing
    with open("gg.txt", "r+") as f:
        # fetching the content
        content = f.read()
        # do your stuff here

        # writing back the content
        f.seek(0,0)
        f.write(content)
        f.truncate()
except EnvironmentError:
    print "oO"
    #better error handling here
    raise
```

See also: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

And for truncate([size]): http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=truncate#file.truncate

Comment: Thanks for this. I shall give it a go and let you know what happens!